# The exterior measure, outer measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I am struggling with this proof:

[image]

If for a fixed $\epsilon$ we choose for each j a cube $Q_j$$\subset$$S_j$ and such that $$\left| S_j\right| \leq (1+e) \left| Q_j\right|$$

Then I have a struggle with the following:
My assumption is(please let me know if I am wrong!)

If $Q_j$$\subset$$S_j$, then $\left| Q_j\right|<=\left|S_j\right|$

Now if that assumption is correct:

then choose $a=\left|S_j\right|$

and $b=\left|Q_j\right|$

Now if 
$$a \leq (1+e) b$$ for all e>0

then $$a \leq b$$

proof: assume the opposite: $$b <a$$
then a-b>0, so we can choose $\epsilon=a-b$

it the follows that $$a \leq b$$ and we end up with a contradiction.

In other words:

$$\left|S_j\right|<=\left| Q_j\right|$$

Therefore,

$$\left| S_j\right| \leq (1+e) \left| Q_j\right|$$

holds for a particular e and not for all if $Q_j$$\subset$$S_j$

But this is then used later on in the proof, where they conclude with since e is arbitrary, but I have just shown that the equation does not hold for all e, and hence e is not arbitrary.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ Theoretical Economist Please have a look.

Comment: I was not notified of this comment because I had not previously interacted with this post. In any case, the answer below appears adequate. I’m happy to try to help if you’re still unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cube $S_j$ depends on $\epsilon$: *after* fixing $\epsilon>0$, you choose $S_j$ such that $Q_j\subseteq S_j$ and $|S_j|\leq(1+\epsilon)|Q_j|$.  So we have a different $S_j$ for each choice of $\epsilon$, and we do not conclude that $|S_j|=|Q_j|$ for any single one of these choices.

This does not change the fact that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, since we fix an arbitrary $\epsilon$ *first* before we choose $S_j$.  For any particular $\epsilon$, it is possible to choose such an $S_j$.